# English to Time

Tags: php, time, timestamp

Does anyone know of a good class / library to convert English representations of time into timestamps?

The goal is to convert natural language phrases such as "ten years from now" and "three weeks" and "in 10 minutes" and working out a best match unix timestamp for them.

I have hacked up some pretty poor and untested code to get going on it, but I am sure there are great parsers out there for calendars and such.

```
private function timeparse($timestring)
{
    $candidate = @strtotime($timestring);
    if ($candidate > time()) return $candidate; // Let php have a bash at it

    //$thisyear = date("Y");
    if (strpos($timestring, "min") !== false) // Context is minutes
    {
            $nummins = preg_replace("/\D/", "", $timestring);
            $candidate = @strtotime("now +$nummins minutes");
            return $candidate;
    }

    if (strpos($timestring, "hou") !== false) // Context is hours
    {
            $numhours = preg_replace("/\D/", "", $timestring);
            $candidate = @strtotime("now +$numhours hours");
            return $candidate;
    }

    if (strpos($timestring, "day") !== false) // Context is days
    {
            $numdays = preg_replace("/\D/", "", $timestring);
            $candidate = @strtotime("now +$numdays days");
            return $candidate;
    }

    if (strpos($timestring, "year") !== false) // Context is years (2 years)
    {
            $numyears = preg_replace("/\D/", "", $timestring);
            $candidate = @strtotime("now +$numyears years");
            return $candidate;
    }

    if (strlen($timestring) < 5) // 10th || 2nd (or probably a number)
    {
            $day = preg_replace("/\D/", "", $timestring);
            if ($day > 0)
            {
                    $month = date("m");
                    $year = date("y");
                    return strtotime("$month/$day/$year");
            }
            else
            {
                    return false;
            }
    }

    return false; // No can do.
}
```

Comment: How about "three years, two days and five minutes into the future" as input?

Comment: Yes, exactly things like that. This is what I need.

Comment: "three years, two days and five minutes" and similar should translate easily into an ISO8601 interval: "P3Y2DT5M" which you can feed to a DateInterval and add to a DateTime object.

Comment: regular expressions won't be able to parse those. what you need is a grammar parser (bison and the like) and that is technically like creating a mini-compiler :P

Comment: This is an interesting challenge. It seems to me it would be great to have a set of user submitted date data to get a feel for how your userbase might phrase dates like this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

e.g.:

```
$string='four days ago';
$d=date_create($string);
$d->getTimestamp();
```

ETA:
which you could extend:

```
class myDateTime extends DateTime {
  static $defined_expressions=array(...);

  function __construct($expression=NULL) {
     if ($exp=$this->translate($expression)) {
       parent::__construct($exp); 
     }
  }

  function translate($exp) {
     //check to see if strtotime errors or not
     //if it errors, check if $exp matches a pattern in self::$defined_expressions
     return $exp, modified $exp or false
  }

}
```

Comment: It looks like this class just uses strtotime() which is not quite adequate or powerful enough...

Comment: It can take both strtotime and ISO8601 (using the constructor) phrases.  What I've found dealing with natural language dates, is that you pretty much have to limit the syntax to a definable set.  You might consider extending DateTime by defining a superset of expressions that you could map to standard PHP date expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime ago I had come across [http://www.timeapi.org](http://www.timeapi.org/) which converts natural language queries into time. It is an API though.

The ruby source code is on github. If need be, I guess you could try to port it to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Just got a notification from PHPClasses, with one of the runner-ups of the monthly innovation award: [Text to Timestamp](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/5721.html)

You could try that...

Comment: Looking at it, it is very nice. You can even configure it and add other items yourself very easily...

Comment: After 20 minutes looking at the examples, I have no clue how to use it even if it does what I want... It looks as if the user is expected to add all the possible queries and map them to a time? "$obj->addTimer(time()-60*60*60, time(), '1 hour ago');"

Comment: Yeah, I admit, the documentation looks horrible. Nontheless, I believe there are a few default strings already "installed"...

Answer (score 0):

[Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s and [GNUStep](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/NSDateFormatter.html)'s `NSDateFormatter` are able to handle such time representations. The GNUStep version is open-source.

Comment: unlikely to help much given the php tag. doubt he's looking for cocoa libraries

Comment: I think the point that mouviciel is trying to make is that he can port the library to php.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I appreciate this suggestion, but there is quite a large barrier to entry there, and I don't know how well it works and I am thus reluctant to invest time. I will look at it if I am unable to find another solution.